# How can I access DOM elements in Polymer elements from a global namespace?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I want to access a DOM element that's in my-app-as-an-element.html from my app.dart global (because it's a method I want to call from several places, e.g. it changes the page title), but as it's wrapped in shadows and all, I can't seem to get at it. There's a trick to do e.g.

```
HtmlElement el;
el = document.querySelector('body /deep/ #page-title');
```

But /deep/ isn't respected in Safari, so that's off the table. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do goes directly against the philosophy of Polymer: the point of all the encapsulation, using Shadow DOM etc. is to have reusable components that manage their own state, DOM included.

If the element that ones that owns that DOM element you are trying to access is a *custom* element (i.e. you or someone at your company has written it), the best solution would be exposing the functionality you need as a public method on that element.

Say for example, your element has a `<h1>` and you want to change its content. You could achieve this as follows:

```
Polymer("my-custom-element", {
    changeTitle: function(newTitle) {
        // this operates on the element's Shadow DOM *only*,
        // NOT the entire page
        document.querySelector('h1').htmlContent = newTitle;
    }
})
```

You can then make this call from your global code:

```
document.querySelector("my-custom-element").changeTitle("My New Title");
```

If the element your are trying to change is owned by a *public* element (e.g. from `core-elements` or `paper-elements`), or anything you've downloaded from some repository, read the documentation and see if it exposes the functionality you need somehow. If not, you could try writing your own custom element that [extends](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#extending-other-elements) that element. In your extended element, you can insert the extendee's Shadow DOM using the `<shadow></shadow>` tag, and manipulate it via your element's JavaScript in the same way as described above.

EDIT: Actually, there IS a way to do what you want directly, although I would only recommend this as a last resort. If you read [Shadow DOM 201](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/), you'll notice that you can access an element's Shadow DOM via the `.shadowRoot` property. This gives you another `Document` object, on which you can use `.querySelector` again, like so:

```
document.querySelector('my-custom-element').shadowRoot.querySelector('h1');
```

Or even

```
document.querySelector('my-custom-element::shadow h1');
```

This gives you a handle on the element, which you can then modify as necessary. But again, I don't recommend using this unless you need quick access to this element for debugging purposes.

Comment: Great insights! What if I have my-app and in it I have child-element and I want to call my-app.changeTitle() from there? Should I import my-app class into child-element so I can call its method, or use your first solution? And curious, why would you not recommend the second and third solutions? An updated answer would rock.

Comment: To expand on that, if I import my-app class into child-element so I can call its method, there is the advantage that the IDE will autocomplete and recognize the method, whereas with document.querySelector('my-app').myMethod(), "the method is not defined for the class Element". But are there disadvantages to importing the parent element into the child element? Seems odd, anyway.

Comment: In fact, the cleanest way to me seems to be to put the `changeTitle()` method into the App global, which then interacts with the element using `document.querySelector('my-app-as-an-element::shadow #page-title');` and then I can call app.changeTitle() from anywhere I import App, but why do you say that's not recommended?

Comment: @DavidNotik I'm not sure what you mean by "import my-app class into child-element", can you clarify that?

Comment: @DavidNotik What I would suggest is putting the changeTitle() method on the element that contains the title you are changing. That will make it part of its public interface, so you can do something like `document.querySelector('my-element').changeTitle("whatever")`. The reason why you should never access another element's Shadow DOM from the outside, if possible, is encapsulation: the Shadow DOM is supposed to be "private" content, to be managed by the element that owns it.

Comment: If you were to, let's say, change the way the title is displayed, your changes will be local to the element. Anybody who needs to change it form the outside can continue calling `changeTitle()` and everything will look the same. That's the whole idea behind component-based architecture (and OOP).

Answer (score 1):

Polyfill for `/deep/` in `querySelector` is work in progress and will be available soon on browsers without native Shadow DOM support.

Comment: Indeed, and important to note here for all. My question is about how to go about this without that (especially given its lack of current support), and the other answer shows I should be thinking about it differently anyhow.